# Example of a family of uniformly integrable random variables that is not dominated?

Tags: probability-theory

If a family $\{X_i:i\in I\}$ of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbf P)$ is dominated, i.e., there exists $Z\in L^1(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbf P)$ such that $|X_i| \le Z$ for all $i\in I$, then it is trivially uniformly integrable. Is there an example of a family of random variables that is uniformly integrable, but not dominated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The family $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is U.I. if for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $K(\varepsilon) < \infty$ such that 
$$ E[|X_i| 1_{|X_i| \geq K}] < \varepsilon $$
for all $i \geq 1$.

Let $X_i = i$ with probability $a_i$, where $a_i \in (0, 1)$, and $X_i = 0$ otherwise, and assume all the $X_i$ are independent. By definition of $X_i$, the expectation of the tail is
$$E[|X_i| 1_{|X_i| \geq K}] = i a_i$$
if $i \geq K$, and is equal to zero otherwise. Set $a_i = 1/(i \log i)$ for $i \geq 2$. Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, if we choose $K(\varepsilon) = e^{1/\varepsilon}$, then for all $i \geq 2$,
$$E[|X_i| 1_{|X_i|\geq K}] \leq i a_i 1_{i \geq K} = \frac{1}{\log i}1_{i \geq K} \leq \frac{1}{\log K} = \varepsilon.$$
Thus the family is uniformly integrable. However, if there were to exist a random variable $Z$ such that $Z \geq |X_i|$ a.s. for all $i$, then we must have $Z \geq i$ w.p. at least $a_i$. However, then 
$$E[Z] \geq \sum_{i=2}^\infty P(Z \geq i) \geq \sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{i \log i} = \infty,$$
and so $Z \notin L^1$.

Answer (score 5):

Uniform integrability refers to the individual (marginal) distribution property, while existence of integrable dominant, to their joint distribution (it is equivalent to the integrability of supremum of absolute values). So there is no reason why they should be equivalent.

If a particular counterexample is needed, the best is to take independent variables (since they are "worst behaved" with respect to joint distribution), as in @snar's answer. But there is an even simpler example: if you take iid variables, which are not essentially bounded (e.g. Gaussian), then the supremum is even infinite almost surely; so not just there is no integrable dominant, there is no dominant at all.

Comment: This is a much better answer that goes to the heart of it, thanks.