# If |X| $\le$|Y| and X$\in$ $\mathcal H$ then $\mathcal H$ is uniformly integrable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $Y$ is some integrable random variable, such that, |X|$\le$|Y| for all $\mathcal H$, then $\mathcal H$ is uniformly integrable. How can I prove this using only the definition of Uniformly integrable. But converse is not true please give a complete example for this. I know that $\mathcal H$ is uniformly integrable if and only if $\mathcal H$ is $L_1$ bounded and $\mathcal H$ is uniform absolute continuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does $\vert X\vert\le\vert Y\vert$ for all $\mathcal H$ mean? I suppose you mean that $\mathcal H$ is a family of random variables, and you have $\vert X\vert\le\vert Y\vert$ for all $X\in\mathcal H$.

As a reminder, $\mathcal H$ is uniformly integrable iff $\sup_{X\in\mathcal H}\mathbb E[\vert X\vert1_{\{\vert X\vert\ge R\}}]$ vanishes as $R$ goes to $+\infty$. If $\vert X\vert\le \vert Y\vert$ for all $X\in\mathcal H$ then
$$
\sup_{X\in\mathcal H}\mathbb E[\vert X\vert1_{\{\vert X\vert\ge R\}}]\le\sup_{Y\in\mathcal H}\mathbb E[\vert Y\vert1_{\{\vert Y\vert\ge R\}}],
$$
where the right-hand side vanishes as $R$ goes to $+\infty$ by dominated convergence. Hence $\mathcal H$ is uniformly integrable.

The converse is not true, see for instance [Example of a family of uniformly integrable random variables that is not dominated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3456437/example-of-a-family-of-uniformly-integrable-random-variables-that-is-not-dominat)